# try/catch to run facebook app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I have 2 links for https://www.facebook.com/natgeo .. (One) if I have the facebook application, it runs on it (Two) if I don't have facebook application, it will run on the browser.

Here is the code:

```
try {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
              }  
              catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
    }
```

Now (Two) runs fine but (One) doesn't work fine, it runs the facebook application on my account, how can I make it running https://www.facebook.com/natgeo on facebook application?

---

Edited

```
        doclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
              }  
            else{  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
    }
};
```

---

### Edited again

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button dadclink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {
        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);

dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
             }  
            else{  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
            }
       )}; 

    } 
}
```

Comment: try if-else n the place of try-catch.This is wrong perception

Comment: Thank you! Is there a sample for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;      
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));  
              startActivity(intent);     
              }  
              else{  
              String natgeo = "natgeo";  
              String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;    
              Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));      
              startActivity(i);   
    }
```

Comment: I used the code and hopefully, it's ok, but the thing there is an error in } and/or ) .. I tried so much but it didn't work .. The code is edited.

Comment: sorry ,I can't understand the error.Will you please explain?

Comment: It's edited again, there is an error there, can you please tell me what is it?